# Microsoft Edge Chromium: auto scrolling won't work in history page

Tags: windows, windows-10, scrolling, chromium, microsoft-edge

Not only would it not let you view in ascending order, but you can't middle-click or use an extension to scroll down. I'm trying to start from the beginning of my history rather than from the end. What should I do? I'm on Windows 10 21H1.

Comment: Did you try End?

Comment: @Tetsujin Did that just now, and still no